# How to setting postfix with nginx reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, email, postfix, reverse-proxy

i want to make a mail server. But i want my mail server not directly connect to internet. So i make another server that accessible via internet and using reverse proxy with nginx. But for some reason reverse proxy cannot connect to mail server. 
Here is my nginx conf:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

stream {
        log_format proxy '$remote_addr [$time_local] '
                 '$protocol $status $bytes_sent $bytes_received '
                 '$session_time "$upstream_addr" '
                 '"$upstream_bytes_sent" "$upstream_bytes_received" "$upstream_connect_time"';

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.stream.log proxy;

        server {
                listen 25;

                #protocol smtp;
                proxy_pass 10.0.1.15:25;
        }
        server {
                listen 110;

                #protocol pop3;
                proxy_pass 10.0.1.15:110;
        }
        server {
                listen 143;

                #protocol imap;
                proxy_pass 10.0.1.15:143;
        }
}
```

Here is my error log

```
2017/09/08 09:02:56 [error] 1444#1444: *5 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 54.240.25.13, server: 0.0.0.0:25, upstream: "10.0.1.15:25", bytes from/to client:0/0, bytes from/to upstream:0/0
2017/09/08 09:06:38 [error] 1444#1444: *7 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 209.85.128.182, server: 0.0.0.0:25, upstream: "10.0.1.15:25", bytes from/to client:0/0, bytes from/to upstream:0/0
2017/09/08 09:07:57 [error] 1444#1444: *9 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 54.240.25.4, server: 0.0.0.0:25, upstream: "10.0.1.15:25", bytes from/to client:0/0, bytes from/to upstream:0/0
2017/09/08 09:16:10 [notice] 1951#1951: signal process started
2017/09/08 09:16:42 [error] 1952#1952: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 74.125.82.46, server: 0.0.0.0:25, upstream: "10.0.1.15:25", bytes from/to client:0/0, bytes from/to upstream:0/0
2017/09/08 09:19:39 [error] 1952#1952: *3 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 54.240.25.8, server: 0.0.0.0:25, upstream: "10.0.1.15:25", bytes from/to client:0/0, bytes from/to upstream:0/0
2017/09/08 09:22:51 [error] 1952#1952: *5 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 74.125.82.50, server: 0.0.0.0:25, upstream: "10.0.1.15:25", bytes from/to client:0/0, bytes from/to upstream:0/0
2017/09/08 09:26:10 [emerg] 9086#9086: unknown log format "main" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:19
2017/09/08 09:27:09 [notice] 9090#9090: signal process started
2017/09/08 09:27:53 [error] 9091#9091: *7 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 209.85.128.176, server: 0.0.0.0:25, upstream: "10.0.1.15:25", bytes from/to client:0/0, bytes from/to upstream:0/0
2017/09/08 09:28:37 [error] 9091#9091: *9 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 209.85.128.170, server: 0.0.0.0:25, upstream: "10.0.1.15:25", bytes from/to client:0/0, bytes from/to upstream:0/0
```

I already check https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/mail-proxy/. But i want redirect sent mail to my mail server

update

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-1-15 ~]$ sudo netstat -nlp | grep :25
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1032/master
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      1032/master
```

already commenting the inet_interface and still the same

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1032/master
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      1032/master
```

Comment: Is your mailserver listening on that port for external connections?

Comment: i think no, because i am using private subnet in aws. And, when i ping from my reverse proxy to my mail servver it works.

Comment: Please run `netstat -nlp |grep :25` on the mailserver and edit the output into the question.

Comment: Why would anybody want Postfix not to listen directly on the internet? Postfix is written by a certified security expert, so it's safe just to do this! If you forward connections via Nginx, then you are loosing the information of the incoming IP address, rendering many spam scans useless. The reason for using Nginx as proxy is to load balance mail traffic from MX to internal storage; do you really have so much mails? I doubt it! If you want to put something before Postfix, take Postscreen, it's made for this purpose!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your postfix only listens on the localhost interface, it does not accept connections from other machines. Configure it to listen on `0.0.0.0`:

Comment out that line in `/etc/postfix/main.cf` by adding a `#` in front.

```ini
#inet_interfaces = 127.0.0.1
```

Or change the address to `0.0.0.0`. Restart postfix afterwards.

Comment: I try to change the address to 0.0.0.0 and it return error " fatal: parameter inet_interfaces: no local interface found for 0.0.0.0" when reload postfix. And removing inet-interface line not return error, but still not work

Comment: have you ran the netstat command again and verified that postfix is now listening on all interfaces?

Comment: still the same 
    tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1032/master
    tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      1032/master

Comment: Then you didn't restart it properly. As long as postfix only listens on 127.0.0.1 it won't accept any mails from other machines.

Comment: Amazing, its work now. Thanks.
The previous attempt error because i just reload postfix not restart it

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Gerald's answer, you also have commented out all the `protocol` directives inside your `server {}` section. They are required in order to determine the correct protocol.

I hope you are already following the official article, [Configuring NGINX as a Mail Proxy Server](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/mail-proxy/).

At least adding `starttls on;` and everything related would be a good idea...

Comment: i already read that link, but i want to make 'forward' email to different server. And in that link i can't find it. proxy_pass directive in mail block didnt work and also protocol directive in stream block didnt work